How to properly combine 2 models with 2 seperate textures and combine certain parts to form a working whole?
I'm new at blender but I wanted to try something that I'm sure has been done before. I'm trying to create new game armor models for Gothic 2 using models and textures already provided by game by basically taking a part from one model and putting on the other to essentially create a new armor. I tried to give it a go and thought I almost had it but when I tried to load it in game, it didn't work so I think I may have missed a few steps along the way.
What I did was import the first armor into blender, I selected 2 Bip parts (Right upper arm and right forearm) in edit mode > separated > deleted everything else. Import the 2nd model > Ctrl + j and join the objects. I thought it worked it first, it looked like it did in material preview but in game it didnt load the new model with the arm added, just the slightly edited 2nd model even though they are joined. I thought it might be a texture issue or maybe something else but I'm not sure. I can provide the asc files and tga files if someone would be willing to look at it/fix it and tell me what I did wrong.Link for necessary add-ons if you decide to take a look at the files 
